# isClosed() показывает что сокет закрыт, но общение с сервером продолжается

Tags: java

Хочу сделать закрытие сокета и соответственно разрыв соединения с клиентом по нажатию кнопки. Произвожу запуск двухпоточного сервера (в одном потоке GUI сервера, в другом потоке идет общение с клиентом). При подключении клиента

```
boolean key = MySocket.s.isClosed();
System.out.println(key);
```

выводится false (значит что сокет открыт).
Далее жму на кнопку и срабатывает метод

```
socketClose(ActionEvent event)
```

выводится true (значит что сокет закрыт)
Но тем не менее, если я в консоли начинаю вводить сообщения, сервер их обрабатывает и присылает ответ. Почему так происходит? Я же закрыл сокет и по идее соединение должно быть разорвано.

Обработчик

```
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.fxml.FXML;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller
{
@FXML
TextField myTextField;

@FXML
Button buttonOff;

public void socketClose(ActionEvent event)
{

    try {
        MySocket.s.close();
       boolean key = MySocket.s.isClosed();
       System.out.println(key);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
   }


}
```

Сервер

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MySocket extends Thread
{
static ServerSocket s;
@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        s = new ServerSocket(8189);
        try(Socket incoming = s.accept())
        {
            boolean key = MySocket.s.isClosed();
            System.out.println(key);

            InputStream inputStream = incoming.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = incoming.getOutputStream();

            try(Scanner in = new Scanner(inputStream))
            {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);
                out.println("Hello! Enter BYE to exit.");

                boolean done = false;
                while(!done && in.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line = in.nextLine();
                    out.println("Echo: " + line);
                    if(line.trim().equals("BYE")) done = true;
                }
            }


        }
    }catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
    boolean key = MySocket.s.isClosed();
    System.out.println(key);

}

}
```

Comment: **Никогда не проглатывайте эксепшены в catch блоках**.  
Уж лучше сделайте `ex.printStackTrace()` - заодно и увидите, если что-то упадёт (возможно, это и будет причиной такого поведения программы)

Answer (score 4):

Очень советую, читайте Java-спеку, там масса полезной информации.
Метод `accept()` создаёт новый экземпляр сокета. Вот и получается что вы закрываете `ServerSocket`, когда для транспорта используете `Socket incoming`.

Информация по [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html), а ещё почитайте про [`Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).
Там масса полезных методов проверки состояния подключения и `in/out` стримов.

А ещё, судя по коду, у вас не реализован клиент в принципе или реализован псевдоклиент (а лучше - приложите код клиента).
Стойкое ощущение что оба потока (и клиент, и сервер) используют один и тот же сокет-канал. Если хотите полноценный эксперимент - делайте 2 различных приложения. Первое - сервер. Запускаете на компе (сервер) и байндите на внутрисетевой ip машины. Второе - клиент. Запускаете на компе (рядом)/мобиле/планшете с подключением к серверу. И засылаете серверу все, что захотите. А ещё нужно чтобы сервер на запросы клиента что-то отвечал (не забыть `flush()`).
Вот это у вас получится полноценное клинт-серверное решение.

**UPD:**
И Боже вас упаси в многопоточке использовать статику!
Используйте паттерн `Dependency injection` без всякой статики, иначе простреленные колени вам обеспечены.